# What happens to offers that are completely fulfilled and are no longer part of orderbook?

Tags: offer

Are these offers removed from account and base reserve requirement lowered for the same automatically once offer is fulfilled?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, assuming that the offers are completely fulfilled (i.e. not partially fulfilled), they're removed from the account and reserve lowered.